# I have nicematrix, which loads some aspects of PGF, but would I benefit from using the full version of PGF?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, nicematrix

I'm new to Stack Exchange, hope this isn't a dumb question to ask.

I have the package `nicematrix`, which in its CTAN package description states:

> The package requires and loads l3keys2e, array, amsmath, pgfcore, and the module shapes of PGF.

I have `pgfplots` and  `tikz` both in my package list, and I am wondering if the comment means that I still need `pgf`? It seems to be an actual package, but different from pgfplots. I would like to have `pgf`, just in case it is ever needed. I don't know if it would be redundant to add it.

I am using Overleaf and having every package set in my preamble.

Comment: Do you mean installed in your TeX distribution? Or loaded in the preamble of your `.tex` documents?

Comment: No, `pgf` is the name of the underlying graphics code that TikZ uses, and is loaded by `tikz` or any package that uses it.  But generally you shouldn't be installing packages from CTAN, but using your distribution to install them if they are not installed.

Comment: @AlanMunn I should have mentioned that I do use Overleaf to load in everything and I have packages in my preamble.

Comment: @DaiBowen I have every package added in my preamble in Overleaf.

Comment: the package will load what it needs, so don't worry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most packages and classes load their dependencies themselves, provided that they are installed in your distribution, so you should never need to worry about adding them to your preamble. So as a general rule, only add packages to your preamble that you are specifically using, and everything else will be loaded automatically.

Since you are using Overleaf, any package you need that is part of the standard TeX Live distribution will be available to you without any worries.

If you're using your own local distribution, and you've installed one of the smaller subsets of the whole distribution then you may need to install packages that aren't found. But this is a separate issue from other packages loading the dependencies themselves.

Comment: Alan, thank you for your answer. I edited my post to show what I wanted to ask better, but I see that you said that tikz loads pgf by default.